# FBML apps fail under HTTPS

Tags: security, url, https, fbml

When setting in the developer console a secure url (https), and trying to load the canvas under facebook:
https://apps.facebook.com/fanta-seriea/
I get the error saying that facebook received an empty responde.
Am I doing something wrong? The certificate is allright:
https://fanta-seriea.com
So why is this happening?
L.

Comment: I found the solution, we also need an intermediate CA
Here you can check the status of your certificate: https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html
Hope this helps

Comment: Did that solution actually work?

Comment: Yes it did :) it took quite a long time to make it work with the bloody plesk panel, but eventually we made it. Hope this will help someone! ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you enable SSL for your FBML app, please make sure that your SSL certificate includes all intermediate certificates in the chain of trust as our SSL validation is strict. You can use third-party SSL analysis tools (e.g., https://www.ssllabs.com/index.html) to check your certificate status and fix any errors (and warnings). If your SSL certificate has problems, you may see "Empty response received" error when you load your FBML canvas app."

From https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/567/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for offtopic.

New [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) says that FBML will die on 1st June 2012. Better go on iframe mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely added a secure canvas URL in your app configuration? On the developer app, go to edit your app and under basic settings you should have URLs in both 'Canvas URL' and 'Secure Canvas URL'

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing the HTTPS version as resolving correctly (although it doesn't fail gracefully if you access that url directly, it pukes errors all over the place) - https://www.fanta-seriea.com/fbfsapro/ - but when I try to access the HTTPS version of the canvas app, it redirects me back to the HTTP version. Is the SSL url set correctly in the SSL url section of your application settings?

Comment: I should note - I'm not getting an empty response error when I try to load the HTTPS version of the canvas app. I just get redirected. That's likely because I'm not a developer of the app.

Comment: Ack. Stupid return = submit. Can you post a screenshot of your app settings screen (excluding your API key info).

Comment: It is correctly set. What kind of errors do you mean? Anyway we currently set the secure url blank, since many users with their security settings ON, couldn't use our app.

Comment: I was looking more for the bit in the edit screen that showed the HTTP and HTTPS areas. Have you tried setting the HTTP version as your Indirizzo Canvas?

Comment: Wait, users with security settings ON couldn't use your app? As of Oct 1, all apps are required to have an HTTPS version, so you'll need to get that resolved - but that explains why you're getting an empty response when you try the HTTPS version. FB is trying to pull your HTTPS url for the HTTPS version, and if there is no URL listed, it won't know where to look.

Comment: Well, it is already set as HTTP right now, as also shown in the previous screen.
Here is the second screeen: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CxOkX.png

Comment: You changed that to non-SSL once you ran into the empty response error? It will be sort of impossible to troubleshoot this if you can't show me the problem at work. But your SSL seems fine, so that's not the problem.

Comment: Wait! :) Right now the field is blank and the answer from facebook is:
`code`Please Update Your Secure Canvas URL
To make sure users can view your app over a secure browser connection (https), please visit the developer console to update your Secure Canvas URL.`code`

Comment: Luca - this conversation is getting a little long, and you don't have enough rep to go into chat. Can you send me an email at snipe@snipe.net and I'll try to help you out? I'll need to see the problem duplicated though, so try to set up a test app using both the SSL and HTTP urls in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing non-secure assets on that page.  Facebook may be providing you with an invalid error message.

You should relativize all URLs that are simple assets.

If you need assets from other domains that are not yours, you can use protocol relative URLs : http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/